# How to specify the width of a pspicture?

Tags: pstricks

In the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1mm}

\begin{pspicture}(60,25)
  \psframe(1,1)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(60,25)
  \psframe(1,1)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The two squares appear next to each other, with no space between them. I expected them to be at least 40 mm apart, because the width of the first pspicture is 60. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think that `auto-pst-pdf`, which is loaded by the `pdf` option, crops tthe pictures to their real size.

Comment: OK, so I can I fix it? Removing the pdf option gives me an error: "Undefined control sequence. \psframe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pstricks}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, it seems that auto-pst-pdf crops ps-pictures to their real size. Actually, you don't even have to specify dimensions for your pspictures. Here is something that does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1mm}

\begin{pspicture}
  \psframe(1,1)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}
\hskip 40mm
\begin{pspicture}
  \psframe(1,1)(20,20)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]